# The right way to design embedded software - examples

Tags: embedded

I'm new to software design.

I'm looking for examples of how to design software correctly.

for example, I was reading this article:
https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/723.php

which begins with an explanation of "how a beginner programmer would have designed the software" and shows in steps what is the right way to do it and explains why he made any change.

Can anyone please recommend me a place where I can find some similar examples?

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: The article you linked is specifically about state machines, not embedded systems design in general.  The question is far too broad to be answered here and requests for answers and resources elsewhere are off-topic on SO.  There are many books on the subject and entire university level degrees, and there is no single "correct way".

Answer (score 0):

I can point you to some [examples](https://repos.modelrealization.com/cgi-bin/fossil/farfalle/wiki?name=Phase%201%20Remote%20Sensor) on one of my projects, but what you will find is the *result* of the design effort and little tutorial as to how to actually design the software. This is not beginner territory, but perhaps it will inspire your thinking. There are references at the end of many of the documents that you can follow up on if you are interested.